# Can't install windows on new laptop

Tags: windows-10, nvme

I bought a new i5 11th gen Lenovo Ideapad 5 15ITL05 laptop.

As, I have done many times before, on any laptop or desktop PC, same USB with working Windows 10 from Microsoft website.

Trying to install, it seems like the laptop doesn't recognize the NVMe drive. (Model in BIOS pictures).

> Couldn't find any drives while installing Windows

1. Even trying checkdisk in cmd, laptop only finds the USB stick.
2. Got portable Ubuntu in USB and got into the desktop. Seems like the NVMe does show up.

   Restarting again, Windows installation cannot find the NVMe to install the operating system.
3. There is a BIOS update available, but I have no clue how to install that file from a USB.

   Instruction from enovo website are saying to install from windows? ‍♂️ well can't even install an operating system.

All the tabs in the bios:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to disable Intel VMD in the BIOS Configuration tab, and then save & exit.

Answer (score 0):

You said this is a new Lenovo Computer.

1. Get the Lenovo USB Installation Key from Lenovo Support and use that. These work great - I use them.
2. Contact Lenovo Support - Machine is under warranty. Lenovo Support is worldwide and applies to the country where you purchased the machine.

They will get you going.

Comment: The laptop is indeed lenovo, but I got it from a local store in my country. Pretty sure no one here have that 'lenovo usb installation key'. 2. I guess I should get lenovo support on this problem. Thanks

Comment: The Store Vendor should be able to help you get the Lenovo USB Key; so can Lenovo Support. Lenovo Support is worldwide.

Comment: I'm posting the same question on the lenovo forums, couldn't find any live chat from their support. Tomorrow morning I will try to call their support in my country. Thanks!

Comment: You should get help there for getting a USB Key - Lenovo support employees do answer questions. It is New Years so good luck and I hope they help. The USB Installation key is what you need.

Comment: I am missing something. An 11th Gen computer, laptop or desktop, should have the key in the bios, All you should have to do is download the latest version of Windows to a flash drive, Boot the flash drive and install. Is the sole issue that you have tried this and can't see the NVMe drive?